# What is the elastic API to view/set `index.refresh_interval`

Tags: elasticsearch

I see that there is a setting for index delay [index.refresh_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting)

This is a dynamic setting, but not per-index.  I can see per-index settings like,

```
GET /my-index/_settings
```

I can see some cluster wide settings like

```
GET /_cluster/settings
```

But neither shows that setting, and I can’t find how I would set that setting using an API.  How can I display and set this setting?

Answer (score 1):

That setting is per index and you can see it like this (`include_defaults` will show the default value that is set if you haven't set any specific value):

```
GET /my-index/_settings?include_defaults=true
```

You can set a specific value dynamically with this call

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
   "index.refresh_interval": "1s"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I misread this `Below is a list of all dynamic index settings that are not associated with any specific index MODULE` as not associated with any specific index.